# What is the best way to position html divs horizontally?

Tags: html, css

This code

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

displays the divs like this.

```
div1
div2
div3
div3
```

I want to display these like

```
  div1   div2   div3   div4
```

The number of divs placed horizontally is not fixed and varies, so I cannot write the css classes with left-padding, width etc defined.

Whats the best way to do it?

Comment: display: inline-block

Comment: use float:left; and width:25%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.container > div {
  border:5px dotted black;
  background:red;
  flex-grow:1;
  padding:2em;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

[Some prefixing may be required depending on your target audience](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

[Learn about all the possibilities here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 1):

Set the display style to inline-block

```
<div id="div1" style="display:inline-block"></div>
<div id="div2" style="display:inline-block"></div>
<div id="div3" style="display:inline-block"></div>
<div id="div4" style="display:inline-block"></div>
```

or better yet

> ```
> <style>
> #div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
>    display:inline-block
> }
> </style>
> ```

Comment: If you use inline flow you should at the very least use `inline-block` for a `div` element.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Inline wouldn't allow you to set the width of the div. Made the edit

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class like

```
<div id="div1" class="inline">lorem</div> 
<div id="div2" class="inline">ipsum</div>
```

and in your CSS :

```
.inline {
float:left;
}
```

Additionaly, you can add some padding...